# How to make bandages around sword hilt

Tags: modeling, workflow

How would I get this effect on my sword hilt?[image]

I would like the bandages to be wrapped around and also have some hanging off for cloth simulation.

Comment: Many ways... You could sculpt the details into a surrounding mesh if you require very detailed hiltwork... Or you could find a bump map online and map it to a surrounding mesh... Or, using the Curve Extras add-on you could create a helix around the haft, convert to mesh, extrude it to a band and modify that. That's three suggestions from hard to easy, that give you most to least satisfactory results. What are your skill levels at 3D modeling?

Comment: I would say I’m pretty good at 3D modelling. The curve extras add on looks useful. Thanks